# XML value frm few nodes based on another node value

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I cannot find solution to my problem, I hope it will be easy to somebody.

Below is part of my xml:

```
<Income>    
    <IncomeItem>
         <TypeId>29</TypeId>
         <Description>test1</Description>
     </IncomeItem>
     <IncomeItem>
         <TypeId>29</TypeId>
         <Description>test2</Description>
     </IncomeItem>
     <IncomeItem>
        <TypeId>29</TypeId>
        <Description>test3</Description>
    </IncomeItem>
</Income>
```

I need output like: `test1 test2 test3`

There will be more types of `TypeId` so value of `Description` has to be based on `TypeId`.

Pseudo code would look like :

```
Select Decsription From XML where TypeId = 29
```

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: @John Saunders, thanks for an advice, will do next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible way :

```
declare @xml XML = '<Income>    
    <IncomeItem>
         <TypeId>29</TypeId>
         <Description>test1</Description>
     </IncomeItem>
     <IncomeItem>
         <TypeId>29</TypeId>
         <Description>test2</Description>
     </IncomeItem>
     <IncomeItem>
        <TypeId>29</TypeId>
        <Description>test3</Description>
    </IncomeItem>
</Income>'

SELECT x.value('Description[1]','varchar(max)') as 'description'
FROM @xml.nodes('//IncomeItem[TypeId=29]') i(x)
```

If you want `Description` values to be concatenated as one row, one possible way is using xquery `for` loop (and `concat()` function to append space between values, if needed) :

```
SELECT @xml.query('for $d in //IncomeItem[TypeId=29]/Description return concat($d, " ")')
           .value('.','varchar(max)') as 'description'
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/1701)**

For reference : [[MSDN] FLWOR Statement and Iteration (XQuery)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190945.aspx)

Comment: Thank you @har07. But this returns more than one value. I need to have this as one value to set other value equal this value. Any suggestions?

Comment: @richardpawel you can use xquery loop to concatenate all relevant `Description` into one value, check my update for detailed query